# Ayuda descargar archivo desde Vuejs+Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, descarga, vuejs

Estoy intentando realizar la descarga de un archivo desde una interfaz hecha con Vuejs, mediante axios, el backend está hecho con Laravel, la funcio es la siguiente

```
    getDownload(id) {
  let uri = `http://mysite.test/api/getdownload/${id}`;
  this.axios.get(uri).then(response => {
    response;
  });
},
```

dicha función va por medio de una ruta api a un controlador que tiene el siguiente método:

```
     public function getDownload($id)
   {
       $name=DB::table('invoices')->where('id_payments',$id)->first();
       $file = storage_path('facturas/'. env('RUC') .'-' . $name->type_document.'-'.$name->serie.'-'.$name->correlative.'.pdf');
       $pdf= env('RUC') .'-' . $name->type_document.'-'.$name->serie.'-'.$name->correlative.'.pdf';
       $headers = array(
               'Content-Type: application/pdf',
               );
       return response()->download($file, $pdf, $headers);
   }
```

con esto logro llamar el archivo, se que es asi, por que si uso otro id me manda error diciendo que el archivo no existe, pero en lugar de la descarga, solo me saca esta respuesta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cómo podría lograr esa descarga?

Comment: Como te queda el nombre del archivo? Symfony HttpFoundation, que administra las descargas de archivos, requiere que el archivo que se descarga tenga un nombre de archivo ASCII. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#file-downloads

Comment: Me parece que al obtener la descarga no te esta retornando como tal un archivo "PDF", sino que esta retornando un blob ó un arreglo de bits que debe ser transformado a PDF, mm no estoy seguro si en el header se deba de agregar un "response-type" y en ese le estableces que esperas como respuesta un blob, y ya tu en front le puedes agregar la extension .pdf, comento esto por la respuesta que te esta dando en el tab del preview que muestras

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude resolver, el problema era que no estaba definiendo la variable RUC en el archivo .env y la funcion  getDownload debería quedar asi:

```
    getDownload(id) {
window.open(`http://mysite.test/api/getdload/${id}`);

},
```